# Distribution of an area

Tags: calculus, probability, geometry, probability-distributions, solution-verification

I've got the problem of trying to guess the probability distribution of the following area $S$:

We draw two lines, $r_1$ and $r_2$, randomly in the plane passing through the origin. So we have two random variables $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that are uniformly distributed on $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$.

Now let's draw the line $x=1$. Then we have a triangle here: OAB. Where A is the intersection of random line $r_1$ with $x=1$, and B is the intersection of the second line $r_2$ with $x=1$.

Now the deal is to guess what's the probability distribution function of that area: the probability that this triangle's area, $S$, is less or equal to x.

My solution to this is the following. I would like that somebody can tell me if I am right or not.

SOLUTION:

First I take $-\frac{\pi}{2} < \beta < \alpha < \frac{\pi}{2}$ and I say that

$f(\alpha,\beta)=\frac{2}{\pi^2}$

is the joint density in the triangle delimited by $-\pi/2 < \beta < \alpha < \pi/2$.

Now I make the following bidimensional change of variables:

$\left\{\begin{matrix}
 X= \frac{\tan{\alpha}-\tan{\beta}}{2}&  & \\ 
 Y= \tan{\beta}&  & 
\end{matrix}\right.$

So the inverse function is:

$\left\{\begin{matrix}
 \alpha= \arctan{(2X+Y)}&  & \\ 
 \beta= \arctan{Y}&  & 
\end{matrix}\right.$

Now, the Jacobian for this function is:

$J = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{2}{(2X + Y)^2 + 1} & \frac{1}{(2X + Y)^2 + 1} \\ 
 0& \frac{1}{Y^2 + 1}
\end{bmatrix}$

And now we can calculate:

$P\{S \le a\} = P\{0 < X < a,-\infty<Y<\infty\}$ as

$\int_{0}^{a}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{2}{\pi^2}|\frac{2}{(4x^2+y^2 + 4xy+1)(y^2+1)}|dy}dx} = \dotsc = \underline{\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan{a}}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. If you want your solution checked you should post it. This is not a forum for discussion.